# Using openmp in a shared library destined for IDL

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, openmp, idl-programming-language

I have a C shared library used by IDL (on Linux). It gets compiled with:

```
make_dll,input_files,exported_routines,compile_directory=compilation_dir,EXTRA_CFLAGS="",EXTRA_LFLAGS="-flto"
```

I'm trying to use openmp in the code of the library. It works in tests compiled from C, but if I add -fopenmp to the EXTRA_CFLAGS, I get the following error when I try to run it from IDL:

```
/usr/local/exelis/idl83/bin/bin.linux.x86_64/idl: symbol lookup error: MyLib.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_parallel
```

So it's not linking to openmp, but adding -lgomp or -lomp doesn't link. What's the correct way to do this ?

Comment: What if you try to link with `libgomp`? Hint: find it with `locate libgomp.a`

Comment: It seems that in fact does link (compiletime) dynamically to openmp but it can only load the openmp libraries exporting the named symbol when run directly instead of via IDL.

Comment: Using the `SHOW_ALL_OUTPUT` and `VERBOSE` keywords should show you the full compilation command and its output which helps debug these types of issues.

Comment: I did it this way: make_dll,...,EXTRA_CFLAGS="... -fopenmp",VERBOSE=verbose,SHOW_ALL_OUTPUT=verbose but nothing extra gets displayed when I compile or when I run... Wrong way to do it ? Sorry, I know very little IDL, only C.

Comment: As purplepsycho indicated, I added -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9 -lgomp to EXTRA_LFLAGS and now it works, thanks.